# Interop Worksheets printoutEx doesn't print first page

Tags: c#, printing, interop

I have an application which generates an excel file. when it is going to be printed by following method, the first page isn't printed.

We pass excel file name as `filename` and Printer Settings via `PrintDialog` as `printerSettings`.
then we use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application` to open then given file and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook` to open the workbook and print whole sheets via `wb.Worksheets.PrintOutEx()`.
in the case when I select XPS Printer as the printer it gets the output filename two times (the time when is printing the first sheet and the time when it is printing other sheets).
when I changed the printing method calling to `wb.Worksheets.PrintOutEx(1,1, ... )` the output file hadn't been created.

```
public static void PrintWorksheet(string fileName, PrinterSettings printerSettings )
    {
        Application excelApp = null;//excel application
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = null;//workbook
        try
        {
            excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();//initialize excel app

            wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(
            fileName,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing); //open workbook


                wb.Worksheets.PrintOutEx(1, wb.Worksheets.Count, printerSettings.Copies, false, printerSettings.PrinterName, false, printerSettings.Collate, false, Type.Missing);//calling print method
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            string err = e.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
//closing the excel app and workbook

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            if (wb != null)
            {

                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wb.Worksheets);

                wb.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wb);
            }

            if (excelApp != null)
            {
                excelApp.Quit();

                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);
            }
        }


    }
```

can anybody help me?

Comment: when you are printing the 3rd parameter for number of copies.. are you setting this via a Dialog ? how are you setting the number of copies for example..?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing the following method instead [NamedRange.PrintOutEx Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.printoutex.aspx)

```
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.NamedRange myNamedRange = Globals.Sheet1.namedRange1;

myNamedRange.PrintOutEx(
  1, 
  wb.Worksheets.Count,
  printerSettings.Copies,
  false, 
  printerSettings.PrinterName, 
  false, 
  printerSettings.Collate, 
  false
);
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what happened with the code you just tried.. did it do the same thing or nothing at all..?